# Strange string not registering correctly

Tags: php, arrays, string

so I've made a clock-time to seconds function, and it works fine when running on it's on, with the test string...say 12:53:13 PM.

But when I put it in another script (via require, or just copy-pasting) I'm finding a problem, I'm not sure if it's specifically due to the function, but this is just weird. The string

"PM" is registering as 6 characters instead of 2 like it should, is what a var_dump says. Any ideas why?

I got the time by exploding an imploding a string of the entire date. This is actually the code

```
$time = explode(" ",$dateallstr);
$time = array($time[5],$time[6]);
$time = implode(" ",$time);

var_dump($time);
//require("timeinsecs.php");
```

And this is what var_dump returns

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "11" [1]=> string(2) "14" [2]=> string(2) "55" [3]=> string(6) "PM" }
```

This is the starting string.

```
DATEALLSTR: string(45) "Tuesday 14th of February 2012 11:14:55 PM"
```

Please help, I have no clue why it would do this.

EDIT:

Ok, got the bin2hex. I'm not sure if this whole thing is just the bin2hex.

BIN2HEX504d3c2f693estring(6) "PM"

Comment: Show us a `bin2hex($time[3])`.

Comment: I'm guessing weird encoding issues (like, for example, a UTF-8 BOM, which wouldn't necessarily show up if you're outputting to UTF-8), but yeah.  we'd have to see the actual bytes of the string to offer any more than a guess.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do the bin2hex thing, gimme a sec....I also realized I didn't mention the var_dump results shown aren't from the $time, but the array in the function.

Comment: Ok I updated with the bin2hex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original string has length 41. It looks like somehow your input carries 4 NUL characters after the text which are not printed but do count to the length:

```
var_dump("Tuesday 14th of February 2012 11:14:55 PM");
 => string(41) "Tuesday 14th of February 2012 11:14:55 PM"

var_dump("Tuesday 14th of February 2012 11:14:55 PM\0\0\0\0");
 => string(45) "Tuesday 14th of February 2012 11:14:55 PM"
```

You can try to `trim()` the input before `explode()`, that should get rid of the extra characters:

```
$time = explode(" ", trim($dateallstr));
```

**Edit**: You've skipped the first step of troubleshooting in PHP: viewing the source to see what the web browser doesn't show. Now that you have posted the hex dump, we see that the last string is actually `"PM</i>"`.

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried that but it's still not working. Still thinking it's 6. Do you have any idea where the \0s came from? And how did you know they were there?

Comment: From bin2hex we see that actually there are no NUL characters, it's just a stray HTML tag.

Comment: Thanks! That was one idiot move right there. I've corrected it so </i> is trimmed out of the dateallstr before it's used by anything. So far it's made 2 txt files based on the date from that string....you don't think the tag would cause problems there do you? Should I delete the txt files it made?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the output from `bin2hex()` function I noticed the sequence `3c 2f 69 3e`. What does it mean? The answer is:

```
</i>
```

View-source the output of the `var_dump()`. It should say something like:

```
array(4) {
[0]=> string(2) "11"
[1]=> string(2) "14"
[2]=> string(2) "55"
[3]=> string(6) "PM</i>"
}
```

The `</i>` is parsed by the browser as a HTML tag and it will not display it!

Comment: Thanks, I never would've spotted that!